# how to eliminate single NA values from data

Tags: r, matrix, na

I have a large matrix and I want to delete NAs from it and shift the next value in its place. I don't want to delete the entire row or column. I need this matrix to be cleaned so I will easily import it to excel.

my matrix:

```
> head(m)

 NA    21005.00    801515021     50  132   6.83
901.56 21049.00    801515025     NA  200   249
```

the desired matrix:

```
> head(m)

21005.00  801515021  50  132   6.83   901.56   
21049.00  801515025  NA  200   249    921.03
```

Comment: If you choose a `tidy` approach, there is the `tidyr::fill` function designed for this purpose. However, I'm assuming you mean data frame and not matrix.

Comment: it is not clear wether you want to delete a single specific NA (as put in the title) or several (/all) NAs (as put in the text)? Once the values are shifted, do you want "the end" of the matrix to be filled with NAs?

Comment: In the desired matrix, where is the `921.03` coming from?

Comment: You say: *I don't want to delete the entire row or column.* But if I compare your input matrix with the desired matrix, you have eliminated the complete first column! And, how to deal with the other `NA` in column 4, row 2 of your matrix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, if I got your task right, you want to eliminate all NA values and shift the next value to its place BY ROW, i.e. to the left from the right.

Here is the code, that achieves this. In order to keep matrix dimensions the same as original, end of new matrix is filled with 0s.

```
# create initial matrix
m <- matrix(data = c(NA, 21005.00, 801515021, 50, 132, 6.83, 901.56, 21049.00, 801515025, NA, 200, 249), 2,6, byrow = TRUE)

c <- 1
n <- list()
# run through initial matrix and if value is not NA, add to new list
for (i in 1:dim(m)[1]) {
    for (j in 1:dim(m)[2]) {
        if (!is.na(m[i,j])) {
            n[[c]] <- m[i,j]
            c <- c + 1
        }
    }
}

# append 0s to the end to keep initial matrix dimensions
for (i in 1:(length(m) - length(n)) ) {
    n[[c+1]] <- 0
    c <- c + 1
}

# convert result to matrix
new <- matrix(unlist(n), ncol = dim(m)[2], byrow = TRUE)
```

Your initial data:

```
NA        21005.00    801515021     50  132   6.83
901.56    21049.00    801515025     NA  200   249
```

The result of the code:

```
21005.00    801515021     50    132   6.83   901.56
21049.00    801515025     200   249   0.00     0.00
```

Comment: That was exactly my problem dear Denis and you solved it, Thank you very much.

Comment: Glad it helped.

Answer (score 1):

Your example implies that after removing the Na values, your matrix has a kind of "natural" structure (i.e. integer below integer, values of similar size in the same column). You could simply do this:

```
new_matrix <- matrix( m[!is.na(m)], nrow = ..., ncol = ..., byrow = TRUE)
```

This will take non-Na values of your matrix, and make a new matrix out of them, the dimension of which you can specify in nrow and ncol.